# Regex for getting information from square brackets

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, square-bracket

I'm attempting to make something like shortcodes in WordPress, and I'm looking for a regex that will take something like `[title:This is a title]` and turn it to just `This is a title`.

It would also be useful if someone could suggest a way to take something like `[code:some code]` and turn that into an array in the form of 
    array(
         [0] => 'code'
         [1] => 'some code')
or
    array(
         'code' => 'some code'

I've tried a few different regexes I've found here and there, but none of them seem to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/\[.*?:(.*?)\]/', '$1', $str);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/YNwkoRq9).

If you wanted to capture the text before the colon, simply wrap it in parenthesis and it will become capturing group 1.

#### Update

> I'm looking to use `preg_match` instead of `preg_replace`

You'd want to use `preg_match_all()` to get all matches.

```
preg_match_all('/\[(.*?):(.*?)\]/', $str, $matches);
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/0xy62).

Alternatively, you could give them named capturing groups.

```
preg_match_all('/\[(?P<identifier>.*?):(?<body>.*?)\]/', $str, $matches);
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/6vnMV).

Comment: I should have clarified -- I'm looking to use preg_match instead of preg_replace.